# How to debug a binder page fault?

Tags: android, debugging, android-binder

```
 190 <7>[   19.600070] Binder_2: unhandled page fault (11) at 0x00000000, code 0x005
 191 <1>[   19.600085] pgd = eb5b8000
 192 <1>[   19.601750] [00000000] *pgd=00000000
 193 <6>[   19.605354]
 194 <6>[   19.605370] CPU: 1 PID: 817 Comm: Binder_2 Not tainted 3.10.49 #3
 195 <7>[   19.605380] task: ecd83c80 ti: ebc2a000 task.ti: ebc2a000
 196 <6>[   19.605390] PC is at 0x737b1e7a
 197 <6>[   19.605397] LR is at 0x7370ff77
 198 <6>[   19.605408] pc : [<737b1e7a>]    lr : [<7370ff77>]    psr: 000f0030
 199 <6>[   19.605408] sp : a5886350  ip : 00001321  fp : 000003f5
 200 <6>[   19.605419] r10: 00000000  r9 : b8867448  r8 : 70c286a8
 201 <6>[   19.605428] r7 : 70c286a8  r6 : 70e02060  r5 : 00000000  r4 : 00000045
 202 <6>[   19.605437] r3 : 00000000  r2 : 70c286a8  r1 : 00000000  r0 : 00000000
 203 <6>[   19.605447] Flags: nzcv  IRQs on  FIQs on  Mode USER_32  ISA Thumb  Segment user
 204 <6>[   19.605456] Control: 10c5387d  Table: ab5b806a  DAC: 00000015
 205 <6>[   19.605466] CPU: 1 PID: 817 Comm: Binder_2 Not tainted 3.10.49 #3
 206 <6>[   19.605492] [<c010bd74>] (unwind_backtrace+0x0/0x11c) from [<c0109954>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14)
 207 <6>[   19.605512] [<c0109954>] (show_stack+0x10/0x14) from [<c0111560>] (__do_user_fault+0xfc/0x148)
 208 <6>[   19.605532] [<c0111560>] (__do_user_fault+0xfc/0x148) from [<c0a43248>] (do_page_fault.part.10+0x318/0x3a4)
 209 <6>[   19.605549] [<c0a43248>] (do_page_fault.part.10+0x318/0x3a4) from [<c0a43300>] (do_page_fault+0x2c/0x98)
 210 <6>[   19.605565] [<c0a43300>] (do_page_fault+0x2c/0x98) from [<c010029c>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x12c)
 211 <6>[   19.605581] [<c010029c>] (do_DataAbort+0x34/0x12c) from [<c0a41b74>] (__dabt_usr+0x34/0x40)
 212 <6>[   19.605590] Exception stack(0xebc2bfb0 to 0xebc2bff8)
 213 <6>[   19.605601] bfa0:                                     00000000 00000000 70c286a8 00000000
 214 <6>[   19.605615] bfc0: 00000045 00000000 70e02060 70c286a8 70c286a8 b8867448 00000000 000003f5
 215 <6>[   19.605627] bfe0: 00001321 a5886350 7370ff77 737b1e7a 000f0030 ffffffff
 216 <4>[   20.217421] tc (2474) used greatest stack depth: 5104 bytes left
```

`kmsg` prints an unhandled page fault after device boot up.
How can I know which service create `Binder_2`? How to debug it?

Comment: is it your code that fails? if so, post it

Comment: This is a Qualcomm project, I did not change any system code(java/c++), just bring up LCD. After boot up, it print this fault, but I can't find any related error message in logcat. I can't find the failed code.

Comment: so it is not your code? i am a bit lost...

Comment: it's not my code, I download it from  Code Aurora. just change kernel device driver part (lcd).